# Warning: Suppressing empty link

Tags: tables, hyperref, cross-referencing

I am trying to refer to some tables that I have labeled, but with some of them this warning appears 'Warning: Suppressing empty link'.
My document class is an 'article' and I am using unnumbered sections and subsections. I have this problem with just some tables (not with all of them) and not with figures, do not really know why. I am using the \hyperref package, eliminating it everything seems fine but obviously the references does not work. I am also using many other packages, here it is the list:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,titlepage,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\author{Marco Tilocca}
\title{-----}
\makeindex
\graphicspath{{./immagini/}}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
```

Do someone know how to fix this problem?
Edit: I am using TexMaker

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get and add it to your question.

Comment: May not be directly relevant, but when I switched from one (conference) template to another, sections became unnumbered, leading to that “suppressing empty link” warning for each `\ref{}` to a section label. Using `\refname{}` seemed a reasonable solution. The text which had been “...see Section _5_” now reads “...see Section _Future Work_”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, the problematic tables are inside of an unnumbered `\section` and you placed the `\label` before the `\caption` command.

Please compare the output of the two different sections in the following example. The first table is correct and get referenced correctly, the second table contains `\caption` and `\label` in the wrong order, thus resulting in the warning "Suppressing empty link" that you also observe.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section*{unnumbered section header}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{a table caption}
\label{tab:example-key} % label is placed after the caption command --> correct
\end{table}

\section*{another unnumbered section header}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\label{tab:incorrect-example-key} % label is placed before the aption command --> wrong
\caption{a table caption}
\end{table}

Correct reference to the table: \ref{tab:example-key}

Wrong reference to the table: \ref{tab:incorrect-example-key}
\end{document}
```